# Java Email with dynamic HTML body

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

What is the best way to have the email template rendered dynamically in the Java mail client ? Any frameworks already addressing this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. JavaMail is just a mail (pop3, smtp, imap,...) client. It does not do any rendering / presentation to the UI.  Templating is something you may use on the server side to create HTML Mails (and maybe send them via SMPT and thus JavaMail to the mail recipients)

Comment: There is no email template rendering dynamically in Java Mail.

Comment: you mean you want to send html template in an email which contains dynamic data?

Comment: Yes. I would like to use a template and fill the template dynamically with the data and send it using java mail client

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of frameworks that can be used to render something to HTML on the server side.  It should be able to use these to generate dynamic HTML too.

However ...

It probably won't help.  As [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056697/dynamic-html-content-in-e-mails) explains, a typical email client won't support Javascript or CSS.  If the email client doesn't support the mechanisms you want to use to make the HTML dynamic, then it makes no difference what you do on the server side.

---

On the other hand, if you just want to generate *static* HTML from a template, there are a few 3rd-party templating engines for doing that.  [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines) lists some of them.

And [this page](http://technologicaloddity.com/2011/10/04/render-and-capture-the-output-of-a-jsp-as-a-string/) describes a way to render a JSP to a string, which could then be embedded into an email.

Answer (score 0):

Keep template in database or in static variable. keep dynamic content in hash tag. lets consider following simple template is in variable 'template'

```
<html>
    <body>
       <p> My name is #NAME </p>

     </body>
</html>
```

replace this dynamic contect with replaceFirst method of string

```
template = template.replaceFirst(#NAME, "NIlesh Kemse");
```

now send mail having this body

```
javax.mail.Message msg=new MimeMessage(session);

MimeBodyPart msgBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
msgBodyPart.setContent(template, "text/html");

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(msgBodyPart);
msg.setContent(multipart);
Transport.send(msg);
```