# How to send an external html page with parameter

Tags: html, netbeans, hyperlink, jakarta-mail, html-email

I am trying to send one email using an external html page, but I want to send it passing parameters to this html page in order to the information would be personally to each email sent, part of the code I am trying is something like below:

`String htmlFile = mypage.html+"?name=Wilerson&surName=Vaz";`

(mypage.html is a file with an html code)

```
message.setDataHandler( new DataHandler( new FileDataSource( htmlFile ) ) );
Transport.send(message);
```

If I send the "mypage.html" without any parameter,  email is being sent properly, but when I try to pass the parameter it fails. Is it possible to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To whoelse can be helpfull in the future, I solved the problem using the approach in the link below, but I am assigning the html file content to a string and replace the value as in the post:

[Java Email with dynamic HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199234/java-email-with-dynamic-html-body)